# Waking Mac over WiFi by Linux

Tags: sleep-wake, wake-on-lan

Does anyone know if a mac can be woken up from the sleep state by a Linux machine over WiFi? The router is non-Apple.

Comment: Please let us know your machine's specs: OS X/macOS version, Mac type and year

Comment: @oa It's El Capital. iMac late 2015.

Comment: @William So a mac can't be woken up if it's connected over WiFi at all?

Comment: @William What about wake on LAN? He said "wake" not "boot".

Comment: @JMY1000 there are guides about this never done it before http://osxdaily.com/2013/12/14/wake-on-lan-mac-iphone/  Yes you are right technically he said wake not boot so as the guide posted it is probably possible.

Answer (score 1):

Under System Preferences -> Energy Saver, select the checkbox "Wake for network access". Note that for Mac laptops this can only be enabled while the laptop is connected to a power source.

[image]

Accessing the Mac over the network from your Linux machine, such as through SSH, will wake the machine.